# Wild Card Subdomain rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've CodeIgniter application where I want to use wildcard subdomains, all setup on the server is done and it is allowing as well, please find below what I'm trying to achieve:

URL: testing.domain.com
will execute: domain.com/user/profile/testing

I don't want redirection but I want it to done through rewrite rules, i.e. it will call backed like index.php?/user/profile/testing and will call that user controller function.

Hope I had explained it perfectly.

Please help me in this as soon as you can.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are looking for (you'd have to adapt it for https usage):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/user/profile/%1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please note that if you have access to the real server configuration and can use that instead of .htaccess style files you should always prefer that alternative. .htaccess style files are notoriously error prone, make things complex, are hard to debug and slow down the server considerably. The code above requires minor changes in that case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I don't want it to redirect. I want that user will see testing.domain.com but in back end it will call index.php?/user/profile/testing.

Comment: This rules does not redirect. It rewrites internally.

Comment: if you put http it will redirect, and if not than it will rewrites internally. I had tried with it but I am using codeigniter, so I changed URL to something like index.php?/user/profile/testing but still it loads home page.

Comment: You might be right, this actually depends a little on your setup. You could try the `P` flag (so `[P,L,QSA]`) to prevent a redirection.

Comment: hmm...it generates 404 not found

Comment: Then you should check the (final) servers access log file to see what url gets requested internally. Most likely this is a path issue.